# Mapping an array into an object, key is not defined

Tags: arrays, dictionary, ecmascript-6

```
const lessons = [
  [ 'Chemistry', '9AM', 'Mr. Darnick' ],
  [ 'Physics', '10:15AM', 'Mrs. Lithun'],
  [ 'Math', '11:30AM', 'Mrs. Vitalis' ]
];

let lessonsAsObject = {};

lessons.map(lesson => {
    lessonsAsObject[lesson[subject]] = lesson[0];
});
```

I want to translate this array into an object, matching the data with the keys, subject, time and teacher.

However the code above returns

> reference error, "subject is not defined".

Comment: What do you expect `subject` to refer to? You haven't specified it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the params from the array, and then create an object for each of them, using the [shorthand and computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

If you want the end result to be an object, instead of array of objects, you can combine them to one object using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), and [`Object#assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

You can use the subject as key:

```js
const lessons = [["Chemistry","9AM","Mr. Darnick"],["Physics","10:15AM","Mrs. Lithun"],["Math","11:30AM","Mrs. Vitalis"]];

const lessonsAsObject = Object.assign(...lessons.map(([subject, time, teacher])=> ({ 
  [subject]: { 
    time,
    teacher 
  }
})));

console.log(lessonsAsObject);
```

Or the index as key:

```js
const lessons = [["Chemistry","9AM","Mr. Darnick"],["Physics","10:15AM","Mrs. Lithun"],["Math","11:30AM","Mrs. Vitalis"]];

const lessonsAsObject = Object.assign(...lessons.map(([subject, time, teacher], index)=> ({ 
  [index]: {
    subject,
    time,
    teacher 
  }
})));

console.log(lessonsAsObject);
```

If you just want an array of objects:

```js
const lessons = [["Chemistry","9AM","Mr. Darnick"],["Physics","10:15AM","Mrs. Lithun"],["Math","11:30AM","Mrs. Vitalis"]];

const lessonsAsObject = lessons.map(([subject, time, teacher])=> ({ subject, time, teacher }));

console.log(lessonsAsObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to end up with is an array of objects where the objects have named properties instead of your array positions, then you could do this:

```
var lessonsList = lessons.map(function(lesson) {
    return {subject: lesson[0], time: lesson[1], teacher: lesson[2]};
});
```

This would give you an array of objects like this:

```
[{subject: "Chemistry", time: "9AM", teacher: "Mr. Darnick"}, 
 {subject: "Physics", time: "10:15AM", teacher: "Mrs. Lithun"}, 
 {subject: "Math", time: "11:30AM", teacher: "Mrs. Vitalis"}]
```

If you're looking for some different type of output, then please show an example of exactly what output you're trying to achieve.

> However the code above returns the reference error, "subject is not
>   defined".

That is because the identifier `subject` is not defined anywhere.  If you intended to use it as a static property name, then you can do `lesson["subject"]`.  If you intended to have `subject` be a variable with some property name in it, then you have to define and assign that variable.